# Comma related issue in Angular data in CSV Format

Tags: javascript, angular, csv

I'm working on Angular 2 in which I have to download data in CSV project. The problem is that I'm encountering comma in my data but that is manipulated as a new cell. I don't want that

```
{
    data.push({
        'Course Name' : item.courseName,
        'Course Type (ELICOS, Vocational Education, Higher Education)' 
        : item.courseTypeDisplay,
        'Total Cost' : item.totalCost,  
    })

    const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
    // let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => 
     JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
    let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => 
    row[fieldName]).join(','));
    csv.unshift(header.join(','));
    console.log(header);
    console.log(csv);
    let csvArray = "\ufeff"+csv.join('\r\n');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob([csvArray], {type: 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' }),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    a.href = url;
    var date = new Date();
    var timeStamp = date.getTime();
    a.download = "Courses"+timeStamp+".csv";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove(); 
}
```

I want my result should show data => Course Type (ELICOS, Vocational Education or Training, Higher Education) in single-cell bit it is shown as
    cell 1 => Course Type (ELICOS ,   cell 2 => Vocational Education
, cell 3 => Higher Education)

Comment: Instead of using this 
        csv.unshift(header.join(','));
use this   
        var header_new = JSON.stringify(header);
        var b = header_new.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')
        csv.unshift(b);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
   data.push({
    'Course Name' : item.courseName,
    'Course Type (ELICOS, Vocational Education, Higher Education)' 
    : item.courseTypeDisplay,
    'Total Cost' : item.totalCost,  
   })

   const header = Object.keys(data[0]);
  // let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => 
  JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
  let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => 
  row[fieldName]).join(','));
  var header_new = JSON.stringify(header); 
  var b = header_new.replace(/[[]']+/g,'') 
  csv.unshift(b);
  console.log(header);
  console.log(csv);
  let csvArray = "\ufeff"+csv.join('\r\n');

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var blob = new Blob([csvArray], {type: 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' }),
  url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  a.href = url;
  var date = new Date();
  var timeStamp = date.getTime();
  a.download = "Courses"+timeStamp+".csv";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  a.remove(); 
}
```